Adding custom validations when integrating Input with React Hook Form using Controller
I am trying to use React Hook Form to setup a custom input field and thus use the useForm hook as below;
const {
        control,
        handleSubmit,
        register,
        formState,
        setValue,
        getValues
    } = useForm({
        mode: 'onSubmit',
        reValidateMode: 'onSubmit',
        shouldFocusError: true,
        defaultValues: {
            myIdFld: '123'
        },
        resolver: yupResolver(schema)
    });

const onSubmit = (data) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    };
    const onErrors = (data) => {
        alert('Errors !');
    };

I have a field config js as below;
let sampleField = {"id":"myIdFld","mandatory":true,"visible":true,"maxLength":5,"items":[],"gridItems":[],"disabled":false,"hidden":false,"readonly":false,"fieldLabel":"My ID 1","pattern":/[A-Za-z]{3}/,"editable":true};

I use the above and pass it to my custom Field component JSX as below;
return (
<>
        <form
            onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => console.log('Save Successful ', data))}>
            <Field name={sampleField.id} control={control} label={sampleField.fieldLabel} formFieldProps={{ necessity: (sampleField.mandatory === true) ?'required': 'optional' }} field={sampleField} {...props} />
      <Button onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit, onErrors)} type="submit" variant="cta">Submit</Button>
    </form>
</>
)

My Field component JSX is as below;
import { Controller } from "react-hook-form"
          
<Controller
    control={control}
    rules={{required: "The field is required"}}
    name={name}
    render={({ field: { ref, ...restField }, fieldState: { error } }) => {
        const validationMessage = error ? error.message : helperText;
        const validationStatus = error && 'error';
        return (
            <FormField validationStatus={validationStatus} {...formFieldProps}>
            <FormFieldLabel {...formFieldLabelProps}>
                {label}
            </FormFieldLabel>
            <Input
                inputRef={ref}
                {...restField}
                {...restProps}
            />
            <FormFieldHelperText>{validationMessage}</FormFieldHelperText>
            </FormField>
        );
    }}
/>        

My Input is kind of a custom controlled component and I am trying to integrate via Controller
Now, the issue is while on submit, I do get the value which I enter in the textbox alerted (which means the field is getting registered).
But I am not able to add any validations and cannot get the error object populated.
Please suggest what I need to add in the above code so that the validations/errors can be
integrated.
Ideally, I am wanting to use the sampleField config js for validation purpose (since it would have attributes like mandatory: true, regex/pattern, etc ...though, I am not sure if I also need to provide the custom error messages.
If yes, I am not sure where can I add those error configurations.
I already tried adding below and passing rules={createValidationRules(field)} to Field;
const createValidationRules = (fieldConfig) => {
        const rules = {};
        if (fieldConfig.mandatory) {
            rules.required = fieldConfig.customRequiredMessage || "This field is required";
        }
        if (fieldConfig.pattern) {            
            rules.pattern = {
                value: fieldConfig.pattern,
                message: fieldConfig.customPatternMessage || "Invalid format"
            };
        }
        if (fieldConfig.maxLength) {
            rules.maxLength = {
                value: fieldConfig.maxLength,
                message: fieldConfig.customMaxLengthMessage || `Maximum length is ${fieldConfig.maxLength}`
            };
        }
        return rules;
    };

But still does not work.

Okay i looked into your Input component and you could try it this way:

Change your Field like this:


const Field = ({ name, control, label, formFieldProps, field }) => {
    // dynamic validation rules
    const validationRules = {
        required: field.mandatory ? "This field is required" : false,
        maxLength: field.maxLength ? {
        value: field.maxLength,
        message: `Max length is ${field.maxLength} characters`
    } : undefined,
        pattern: field.pattern ? {
            value: field.pattern,
            message: `Invalid format`
    } : undefined,
    };
    return (
        <Controller
            control={control}
            name={name}
            rules={validationRules}
            render={({ field: { ref, ...restField }, fieldState: { error } }) => {
        const validationMessage = error ? error.message : '';  // Error Messages
        const validationStatus = error ? 'error' : undefined;
        return (
            <FormField validationStatus={validationStatus} {...formFieldProps}>
                <FormFieldLabel>{label}</FormFieldLabel>
                <Input inputRef={ref} {...restField} />
                {error && <FormFieldHelperText>{validationMessage}</FormFieldHelperText>}
            </FormField>
            );
        }}
        />
    ); };



use handleSubmit to handle onSubmit and onErrors:


<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit, onErrors)}>
    <Field 
    name={sampleField.id} 
    control={control} 
    label={sampleField.fieldLabel} 
    formFieldProps={{ necessity: (sampleField.mandatory === true) ? 'required' : 'optional' }} 
    field={sampleField} 
    {...props} 
    />
    <Button type="submit" variant="cta">Submit</Button>
</form>


I dont know if thats the issue but react-hook-form does things the way react-hook-form wants to do, so you are gonna have to try different ways until it works.

Thanks. Again, I get the alert with empty string for the input if I keep it empty. However, I do not see the error. Not sure if there is anything to do with register. I can share my Input component code link if you would like to look into that.

Sure maybe I could find the problem

Sure. Here it is https://github.com/jpmorganchase/salt-ds/blob/main/packages/core/src/input/Input.tsx

Again, I am consuming the above Input via Controller I have shown above

Im sorry I dont really get why it won't work right. Your input component looks good and you integrated react hook form the right way. Idk I would love to help. I will look into it a bit more and text you if I got something

Sure. No rush. I assume there is nothing related to passing register and rules via the same...But again, feel free to look in all directions.

I edited my answer. If you got time and still dont have a fix, try it.
